# expected identifier or '(' before 'int'

Tags: c

I wrote this piese of code for prim's algoritm and I get this error: "expected identifier or '(' before 'int' ". I have a header file, a main and another .c file.
This is the error: "s algoritm 2\prim.h|6|error: expected identifier or '(' before 'int'| s algoritm "
Can anyone tell my why I get this error?

HEADER file

```
#ifndef prim
#define prim
#define nmax 10

void prim(int mat[nmax][nmax],int x,int n ,int m);

#endif // graphs
```

PRIM.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "prim.h"


void prim(int mat[nmax][nmax], int x, int n, int m)
{
int viz[nmax], u, v, min, total = 0;
int i, j, counter;

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    viz[i] = 0;
}

viz[x] = 1;

for(counter = 0; counter < m; counter++)
{
    min = 999;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(viz[i]==1)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if(viz[j]!=1)
                {
                    if(min > mat[i][j])
                    {
                        min = mat[i][j];
                        u = i;
                        v = j;
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
        }

        viz[v] = 1;
        total += min;
        printf("\nMuchie gasita de la %d -> %d de weight %d", u, v, min);

    }

    printf("\nDimensiunea arborelui de acoperire minim: ", total);

}
```

The MAIN.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "prim.h"

void main()
{
    FILE *fin;
    char sursa[20];
    int mat[nmax][nmax], n, m, i, j, x;

    printf("\nIntroduceti fisierul sursa: ");
    gets(sursa);

    fin = fopen(sursa, "r");
    if(fin == NULL)
    {
         perror("\nEroare la deschiderea fisierului!");
         exit(-1);
    }

    fscanf(fin, "%d %d", &n, &m);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){

            fscanf(fin, "%d", &mat[i][j]);

          if(mat[i][j] == 0)
        {    
             mat[i][j] = 999;
        }
             fprintf(stdout, " %3d ", mat[i][j]);
     }
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
}

printf("\nIntroduceti nodul sursa: ");
scanf("%d", &x);

prim(mat, x, n, m);
}
```

Comment: Please show the ENTIRE error message IN YOUR QUESTION

Comment: that is not ***in your question***.   Reading that comment is hard!  You should [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23789100/edit) your question to put the error in the question itself!

Comment: You need to reformat your first paragraph to highlight the error message (which seems odd to me). By the way, it's *algorithm*.

Comment: sorry for my english skills.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You #define `prim` in your header file, and then use that term in your program. The preprocessor doesn't care what it means there, it just replaces it according to your `#define` directive, with nothing in this case.

Try to avoid using small letters and simple terms as #define values (try avoiding #define at large unless you know how to use them), it leads to such cases. For starters change your #defines to capital letters

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your header file:

```
#ifndef prim
#define prim
#define nmax 10

void prim(int mat[nmax][nmax],int x,int n ,int m);

#endif // graphs
```

It looks like you were trying to set up an include guard, but you re-used `prim`; this is a problem, because now every time the preprocessor sees `prim` in your source code, it will replace it with an empty string, so your function declaration becomes

```
void (int mat[10][10],int x, int m ,int m);
```

and the definition becomes

```
void (int mat[10][10], int x, int n, int m)
{
int viz[10], u, v, min, total = 0;
...
```

and the function call in `main` becomes

```
(mat, x, n, m);
```

A common convention for include guards is to use all uppercase with a `_H` suffix, so your header should be written as

```
#ifndef PRIM_H
#define PRIM_H
#define nmax 10

void prim( int mat[nmax][nmax], int x, int n, int m );

#endif // PRIM_H
```

Comment: That was the problem!! Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

After removing 1st line in .h file, code compiles in MS VISUAL 2010. I didn't make any other changes. Maybe you should try changing your compiler.